# Using Shell Open specific ACCESS form

Tags: vb.net, shell, ms-access, vb6

I'm trying to open a specific Access form using `Shell` in vb6, but after reading lots of documentation, I am unable to find out why Access can not find my database.

```
dim ss as string
ss = MSAccFolder & "\MSAccess.exe" & " " & app.path & "\database\db.mdb /cmd " & ""formname""
Shell sss, vbNormalFocus
```

The interesting thing that I shoud tell you is that after a while Access opens and it says that the database with this path does not found

```
MYAPPPATH/MYFORMNAME.mdb
```

What's wrong?

Comment: I've seen similar before when just double clicking the Access shortcut. The only solution I had was to ope Access then drag the file in manually.

Comment: It would have been nice if you'd actually pasted the code directly from the IDE. The sample you have got above has at least two mistakes.

Comment: @MarkBertenshaw: I did there was no error on running the shell. the problem was that Access could not find the DB. However i found the solution. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the solution.

```
    Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long

'This will open Access with the specified name

    Dim ss As String
    ss = App.path & "\database\db.mdb"
    ShellExecute Me.hwnd, vbNullString, ss, vbNullString, "C:\", SW_SHOWNORMAL
```

Answer (score 3):

`app.path` may contain spaces. Surround app.path & "\database\db.mdb" with quotes. I apologise but I have forgotten the VB syntax to do it.

Comment: I guess this problem raised from app.path, too but i don't agree with you on spaces. if it was so, the example in microsoft website should not work,too. see this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/207672

Comment: @DavidPeterson The example you linked to is for including the path in a short cut (step 2 of method 2) and not including it in code. The short cut handling code is smart enough to parse out spaces. The help for Shell (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe736fyk(v=vs.71).aspx) states that "You should always enclose the entire path and file specification in quotes".

Comment: +1 but why not link to the **VB6** version of the Shell documentation :)  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242087(v=vs.60).aspx